# How do you change the value of a variable during a navigation link in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, navigation, swiftui

How do you change the value of a variable during a navigation link?

I have a variable defined as

```
@State var numberChange: Int
```

and I'd like it to change when the user presses a button, even though the button has a navigation link attached to it, with

```
NavigationLink(destination: destinationView(numberChange: self.numberChange)) {
                            imageLink(imageName: "imageName")
                            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

If I try

```
destinationView(numberChange: self.numberChange = 4)
```

Xcode throws

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Int?'

I've only been programming for a few months, and I've been working in Swift for less than a week, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question.

Thanks in advance

Miles

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should pass an integer to the function (instead of an operation):

```
destinationView(numberChange: self.numberChange)
```

or

```
destinationView(numberChange: 4)
```

That is cause of the error.

---

Second of all, you must **NOT** change a `State` property from outside of a view. One of the good practices around this is to declare all `State` properties as a `private var`.

---

Third of all, You can use `.onAppear()` :

```
.onAppear {
   self.text = "Goodbye world"
}
```

This will call whenever the view is about to appear. You can pass the value to the next view if you need and remember, you can use `binding` mechanism to change the UI whenever the value changes (instead of waiting for navigation)